# Is it possible to export ttk Treeview to pdf?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have been working on a GUI and the results are displayed in a Treeview. I was wondering if it is possible to export this information as pdf, since I did not find anything on the internet.

Thank you

Comment: Depends: **1.** Data only, yes **2.** Screenshot, yes **3.** Table, as `Canvas Text` items` , yes Read up on [Canvas - `postscript`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/canvas.htm#M61)

Comment: Thanks, i just extracted the data as list to see if I can append somehow to a pdf file

Comment: Is your issue solved?

Comment: No bro, I don't think so :s

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no support in tkinter to export treeview data to pdf.

Comment: So, theres nothing to do? :c

Comment: Well, there are ways to create pdf in python. You will have to use another library and recreate the treeview data yourself.